Relation between $(\Omega, \sigma(X, Y), \mathbb{P})$ and $(\Omega \times \Omega, \sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y), \mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P})$
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be probability space, $(S_1, \mathcal{S_1}), (S_2, \mathcal{S_2})$ be measureable spaces, and $X:\Omega \rightarrow S_1$, $Y:\Omega \rightarrow S_2$ be independent random variables. I observed an interesting relation between $(\Omega, \sigma(X, Y), \mathbb{P})$ and the product measure space $(\Omega \times \Omega, \sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y), \mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P})$, and looking for literatures dealing with this.
For, define $Z : \Omega \rightarrow S_1 \times S_2$ by $Z(\omega) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega))$, and $X \times Y:\Omega \times \Omega \rightarrow S_1 \times S_2$ by $X \times Y(\omega_1, \omega_2) = (X(\omega_1), Y(\omega_2))$. Observe for $A \in \mathcal{S_1},  $, $ Z^{-1}(A \times B) = X^{-1}(A) \cap Y^{-1}(B)$ and $X \times Y^{-1}(A \times B) = X^{-1}(A) \times Y^{-1}(B)$.
By such realation on $\pi$-system generating $\mathcal{S_1} \times \mathcal{S_2}$(where $\mathcal{S_1} \times \mathcal{S_2}$ denotes product $\sigma$-algebra), we can show

Family of $X^{-1}(A) \cap Y^{-1}(B)$ and $X^{-1}(A) \times Y^{-1}(B)$($A \in \mathcal{S_1}, B \in \mathcal{S_2}$) are $\pi$-system generating $\sigma(X, Y)$ and $\sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$, repectively.
$Z$ and $X \times Y$ are r.v.
$Z^{-1}(\mathcal{S_1} \times \mathcal{S_2}) = \sigma(X, Y)$, $X \times Y^{-1}(\mathcal{S_1} \times \mathcal{S_2}) = \sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$
Denote the probabilistic law(measure) on $\mathcal{S_1} \times \mathcal{S_2}$ by r.v. $W$ as $\mu_W$. Then $\mu_Z = \mu_{X \times Y}$.

Combining the properties seems to suggest an interesting relation between $(\Omega, \sigma(X, Y), \mathbb{P})$ and $(\Omega \times \Omega, \sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y), \mathbb{P} \times \mathbb{P})$. These two measure spaces feels to have roughly the same measure structure built by $X$ and $Y$. Since it seems so natural, I believe this relation have already been studied before. Please give some sources to learn more about this.

$\sigma-$field comes before any probability measure, and is thus completely free of any probability measure.

To repeat what Landon Carter says, relation between $\sigma(X, Y)$ and $\sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$ has nothing to do with independence.

Actually you're right. I should have said about relation between the two measure spaces. My point was, combining the property 2 and 3 I have mentioned, $\sigma(X, Y)$ and $\sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$ seem to have roughly the same measure structures. I'll edit my question.

You are using a strange notation: $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb P\times\mathbb P$ for measures on the product space which you want to compare. Apart from this I can assure you that these relations have already been studied. A well known theorem in probability theory says that two random variables are independent if and only if their joint distribution is the product measure of the two individual distributions. Reference: any standard probability book.
